# using Bootstrap Tooltip container Not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I'm using Bootstrap tooltip, but I facing with a problem,
the tootip always display the bottom of body,
when i set container, it not changed,
Can anyone tell me What happend?

[photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG0wk.png)

[photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNyLD.png)

Bootstrap version is v3.3.7

```
function onError(inputElement, message) {
        updateClasses(inputElement, classes.error, classes.success);
        debugger;
        if (inputElement.data('val-appendto') !== undefined) {
            inputElement = $('#' + inputElement.data('val-appendto'));
        }

        var container = (inputElement.is('input') || inputElement.is('textarea') || inputElement.is('select'))
            ? inputElement.parent()
            : inputElement;
        var options = { trigger: 'manual', container: container };
        inputElement.tooltip(options);
        inputElement.attr('title', message)
            .tooltip('_fixTitle')
            .tooltip('show');

        inputElement.addClass('is-invalid');
    }
```

[photo3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ6Jb.png)

I set the container, but it still display the bottom of body,
I expect it created near the text element.

Comment: Please have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using ?